# How to print all words stored in a Tree , wherin trie has been implemented using Hashmap in Java?

Tags: java, hashmap, trie

I want to print or retrieve all the words stored in Trie Data Structure. This is because I want to compute Edit distance between a misspelled word and a word in Dictionary. 
Therefore I was thinking of retrieving each word from Trie and compute Edit distance. 
But I am not able to retrieve. I want some code snippet for this. 
This is how I have implemented  the Trie using `HashMap` in Java

Now please tell me how to write code for printing all words stored in Trie. Any help is very much appreciated

**TrieNode.java**

```
package triehash;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class TrieNode implements Serializable {

HashMap<Character, HashMap> root;

public TrieNode() {
   root = new HashMap<Character, HashMap>();   
   }
}
```

**TrieDict.java**

```
package triehash;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class TrieDict {   
 public  TrieNode createTree()
 {
     TrieNode t = new TrieNode();
     return t;
 }

 public void add(String s, TrieNode root_node) {
    HashMap<Character, HashMap> curr_node = root_node.root;
    s = s.toLowerCase();
    for (int i = 0, n = s.length(); i < n; i++) {
        Character c = s.charAt(i);
        if (curr_node.containsKey(c))
            curr_node = curr_node.get(c);
        else {
            curr_node.put(c, new HashMap<Character, HashMap>());
            curr_node = curr_node.get(c);
        }
    }
    curr_node.put('\0', new HashMap<Character, HashMap>(0)); // term
  }

 public void serializeDict(TrieNode root_node)
 {    
   try{
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("/home/priya/NetBeansProjects/TrieHash/dict.ser");

    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);   
    oos.writeObject(root_node);
    oos.close();
    System.out.println("Done");

   }catch(Exception ex){
       ex.printStackTrace();
   }
}

 public void addAll(String[] sa,TrieNode root_node) {
    for (String s: sa)
        add(s,root_node);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    TrieDict td = new TrieDict();
    TrieNode tree = td.createTree();

    String[] words = {"an", "ant", "all", "allot", "alloy", "aloe", "are", "ate", "be"};
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
      td.add( words[i],tree);       
    td.serializeDict(tree); /* seriliaze dict*/
 }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, it's worth noting that the declared type of the `root` instance variable is a little odd. (Specifically, the value type of `HashMap<Character,HashMap>` excludes some of the generics you'd rather it used.) The code below should work, but you'll get some warnings as a result of this. You might try refactoring your code to use the type `HashMap<Character,TrieNode>` instead. Sorry if that's pedantic. :)

Try this, added as methods to `TrieNode`:

```
public Set<String> computeWords() {
    Set<String> result;

    if(root.size() == 0)
        result = new HashSet<String>();
    else
        result = computeWords(root, "");

    return result;
}

protected static Set<String> computeWords(HashMap tree, String prefix) {
    Set<String> result=new HashSet<String>();

    if(tree.size() == 0)
        result.add(prefix);
    else
        for(Object o : tree.keySet()) {
            Character c=(Character) o;
            prefix = prefix+c;
            result.addAll(computeWords((HashMap) tree.get(c), prefix));
            prefix = prefix.substring(0, prefix.length()-1);
        }

    return result;
}
```

For a given `TrieNode` object `t`, `t.computeWords()` would return the set of all words words encoded in `t`.

I believe this answers the question you were trying to ask. However, to answer the question as stated in the header, you'd print all the words for the same `t` like this:

```
for(String word : t.computeWords())
    System.out.println(word);
```

Also, this definitely isn't the most efficient implementation, especially since we create a bunch of `HashSet` objects in `computeWords(HashMap,String)`, but it should work!

**EDIT**: This code also assumes that you terminate words with an empty `HashMap`. If you terminate words with `null` instead, you'd need to update the `if(tree.size() == 0)` check in the `static` method with `if(tree == null)`. Sorry, should have called that out.

**EDIT**: Explained how to print all the words, just in case it wasn't clear.

**EDIT**: Fixed empty trie case.

Comment: @sigpwned.. Thanks for your help. I am facing now another issue.  The below code does not work        
         
String word1="ant"                                                           Set<String> Words = ts.computeWords(tree.root);
         
        if (Words.contains(word1))
            System.out.println("Word exists");

Comment: Hi @user2281107. That sounds like a separate question, so you should probably ask it as another top-level question.